# Como pasar información de una tabla a otra, teniendo en cuenta que la tabla2 tiene mas campos que la tabla1. SQL

Tags: html, mysql, css, c

Necesito que los campos de la tabla1 pasen a la tabla2 cuando le de clic en un botón, pero teniendo en cuenta que la tabla2 tiene mas campos que la tabla1.. AYUDAAA!

[image: tabla1 clientes_info]

[image: tabla2 hoja_de_venta]

Comment: Hola para poder ayudarte tienes que compartir tú código, mostrarnos donde te lanza error que has intentado. Te invito ha hacer un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y sobre cualquier duda puedes visitar esta [sección de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help). Suerte

Comment: Lo estoy intentado hacer con un trigger, pero no me devuelve lo que necesito de una tabla a otra (eso en php de sql (xampp)), y adicional que al hacer clic me cargue la información de tabla1(clientes_info), a tabla2(hoja_de_venta) en html, pero no se como :(                                                      DELIMITER @ 
CREATE TRIGGER hoja_de_venta BEFORE INSERT ON cliente_info
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO hoja_de_venta VALUES (new.documento,new.nombre,new.apellido,new.telefono,new.email, curdate(),'Agregado');
END;
@
DELIMITER ;